# I got a fatal error when I went to install Open Web Analytics

Tags: php

Fatal error: Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file "/var/www/html/owa/owa-data/logs/errors_d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.txt" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/owa/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:146 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/owa/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(48): Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write() #1 /var/www/html/owa/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(327): Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle() #2 /var/www/html/owa/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(565): Monolog\Logger->addRecord() #3 /var/www/html/owa/modules/base/classes/error.php(222): Monolog\Logger->error() #4 /var/www/html/owa/modules/base/classes/error.php(181): owa_error->logMsg() #5 /var/www/html/owa/modules/base/classes/error.php(254): owa_error->log() #6 /var/www/html/owa/modules/base/classes/error.php(104): owa_error->logBufferedMsgs() #7 /var/www/html/owa/owa_calle in /var/www/html/owa/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php on line 146

Any clue why this happened and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: Read the message "could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied". So you should check the file permissions on the server running this code. The log files should be writeable to the php user that executes your schripts.

Comment: @akrys how do I figure out the php user?

Comment: It‘s the system user that executes php. Usually on a web server environment it‘s "www-data" but it depends on configuration. The user can be another if the scrupt runs as cronjob.

Comment: Best way would be to create a file via php and have a look which user created it.